# Efficient way to update one of the childs of a ExpandableListView group?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a ExpandableListView with some groups, and each group haves only one child, with a string on it.

I have a thread that get's some updated data and **each second** calls a handler that updates the string of one of the childs of the ExpandableListView and then calls this method to refresh the view and show the updated data to the user: `((BaseExpandableListAdapter) mAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();`

This is the update handler:

```
infoUpdateHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);   
                children[2][0]=getUpdatedInfo();
                ((BaseExpandableListAdapter) mAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

The problem is that when i'm scrolling the expandable list view, i can see how the scroll is showing low performance, it stops sometimes. I think that it is because this call `((BaseExpandableListAdapter) mAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();` is updating all the ExpandableListView.

**Does not exist a better way to update a expandable list view? Maybe a way to update only the child that you want to update?**

Thanks

Comment: Updating listview each second is not good in terms of scroll performance. Instead u could consider some delay after each updation.

Comment: i need to do it, one of the things i'm updating is a clock with a amount of time, including seconds

Comment: i'm sure there is a way to do it efficiently, you can see an example in the status zone of the options of the phone, it haves a uptime time counter that is being updated each second, and the scroll works perfect

Comment: ok. I am not sure but u could consider not to update listview while scrolling atleast... As soon as scroll completes, again starting update

Comment: how can i check if the expandablelistview is being scrolled?